# How to remove Wrong relations after LogicalExpand?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I have a complex relation which I need to expand and represnt it clear and nice. So I used LogicalExpand (LE). I know LE does only the simple expansion and nothing further. but it creates some wrong relations which I am sure besaed on my source relation. So how to remove or get most correct output, please look at this example:

```
Simplify /@ 
LogicalExpand [(w == wP || z < x) && (w == wP || w > x + 2 z) && (wP == 4 + 2 x + z || z >= x || w <= x + 2 z) && z == zP && (x + z == yP || z < x) && 2 x + z == xP && (x + 2 z == yP || z >= x)]

(w==wP && x+z==yP && 2 x+z==xP && z==zP && z>=x)||  #1 right
(w==wP && x+z==yP && 2 x+z==xP && wP==4+2 x+z && x+2 z==yP && z==zP)|| #2 Wrong
(w==wP && x+z==yP && 2 x+z==xP && x+2 z==yP && z==zP && w<=x+2 z)|| #3 Wrong
(w==wP && 2 x+z==xP && wP==4+2 x+z && x+2 z==yP && z==zP && z<x)|| #4 wrong
(w==wP && 2 x+z==xP && x+2 z==yP && z==zP && z<x && w<=x+2 z)|| #5 right
(2 x+z==xP && wP==4+2 x+z && x+2 z==yP && z==zP && w>x+2 z && z<x) #6 right
```

As you see above lines 2,3 and 4 are definitely wrong, as I am sure based on my source relations. For example, you see in line #2 **two different yP is created. x+z==yP and x+2 z==yP** . I just need the rest of it. IS there any way for this problem? ***How to return numbers 1,5 and 6 ?***

Answer (score 3):

Get an overview

```
te = (w == wP || z < x) && (w == wP || 
 w > x + 2 z) && (wP == 4 + 2 x + z || z >= x || w <= x + 2 z) && 
z == zP && (x + z == yP || z < x) && 
2 x + z == xP && (x + 2 z == yP || z >= x);

TraditionalForm[
te //. Or -> 
Composition[(Column[#, Right, Background -> {{White, LightGray}}, 
   Frame -> All] &), List]]
```

[image]

```
red = Reduce[te, Reals];

TraditionalForm[
red //. Or -> 
Composition[(Column[#, Right, Background -> {{White, LightGray}}, 
   Frame -> All] &), List]]
```

[image]

```
le = LogicalExpand[te];

TraditionalForm[(Simplify /@ le) //. 
Or -> Composition[(Column[#, Right, 
   Background -> {{White, LightGray}}, Frame -> All] &), List]]
```

[image]